# PHP : how to use SOAP to access a class methods that are present on a different server

Tags: php, html, web, soap

I am trying to access the methods of a class that are present on a different server on my current server , so that i can share their methods , so that dont have to write the same methods again

So i configured and installed the PHP SOAP extension on my system..

After that i created a `SOAPService.php` file on my server side which has the following code.

```html
 
<?php
// *** The SOAP class wrapper: myClassSoapServer.php ***

require_once('bc_seller_classes/Vendor/Vendor.php');

$options = array('uri' => 'http://merchants.bookchor.local/bc_seller_classes/Vendor/');
$SOAPServer = new SoapServer(null, $options);
$SOAPServer->setClass('Vendor');
$SOAPServer->handle();
?>
```

Here as you can see i wanted to access the Vendor class .

And on the client side i made `soap.php` with the following code , so that i could access the `get_module()` method of the Vendor class.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <?php

  // *** The SOAP way: using a class remotely ***

  $options = array(
    'location' => 'http://merchants.bookchor.local/VendorSoapService.php',
    'uri'      => 'http://merchants.bookchor.local/'
  );
  $hdl = new SoapClient(null, $options);
var_dump($hdl);
  $data = $hdl->get_module();
  echo "hi";
  var_dump($data);
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i execute `soap.php`  on the client side it gives the following error

`Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document`

So where am i going wrong .

PS: the get_module() function returns an array which i would like to use here.
and Both the `SOAPService.php` and `soap.php` are placed in the root folder of the project .